# Home Network with a wireless router

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-router, file-transfer

I want to create a home network. Sounds easy, well at first it did. So far I managed to connect the Laptop to the router and to Internet, but I can't connect the PC to the Laptop using the cable-router-wireless path.
Who can explain to me how to connect a Wireless Router, a wireless Laptop (Win7) and a cable connected PC (WinXP) in a network so they can exchange files and connect to the internet from scrap?

Answer (score 1):

Goto your laptop and get the following info:

Open a cmd prompt (run "cmd").
Type "ipconfig".
Find the IP4 Address, subnet mask & default gateway.

Now goto desktop and do the same and compare the two computers:
The IP4 address should be within the same range, but the subnet mask and default gateway should be the same.

Open the network connections properties on the desktop and set the static ip4 properties to match the laptops.

To share files the computers must be on the same workgroup. Goto control panel "system" and set the desktop computer name to what the laptop workgroup name is. Win7 default is set as "HOMEGROUP", XP default workgroup is called "WORGROUP". They must be the same on all computers.

Answer (score 0):

you plug them all into the cable router. and if it doesn't have enough holes, you get a network switch plug that into the cable router, and plug them all into the network switch